# How can I print a list "nicely" and numbered?

Tags: python

I need to print a list in Python nicely and numbered. For example, if this is my list:

```
list = ["hello", "dad", "milk"]
```

this is the output I want:

```
[1] -hello
[2] -dad
[3] -milk
```

This is what I have tried:

```
list = ["hello", "dad", "milk"]
list_element = 0
stuff = len(list)
while stuff != list_element:
            element = list[list_element]
            print(f"[{list_element}] -{element}")
            list_element = list_element + 1
```

and this is the output I get:

```
[0] -hello
[1] -dad
[2] -milk
```

but I don't know how to make it start from 1 (I know in programming you start with 0, but I want to start with 1!)

edit:
I forgot to mention this was homework and we didn't learn about the for loop yet so my teacher said I shouldn't use it as to not confuse my classmates lol

Comment: `list_element + 1`? Also this is a much more natural fit for a `for` than `while` loop, this would be trivial if you `enumerate`d (and don't shadow `list`, use a different name).

Comment: Python's *index* starts at 0. You can set any increments to start at whatever number you'd like

Comment: `list_element = 0` You're telling it to start at zero.  If you want to start at 1, do that instead!

Comment: You can print whatever you like in the `print()` call. All that matters is that you _access_ the list element with the zero-based index. Also, the pythonic way to loop over a list is using `for element in list`. If you want the index too, do `for index, element in enumerate(list)`. Read the [docs for `enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to see if it can do what you want to do without having to add 1 to your print statement.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so the loop can end

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean "why do you have `list_element = list_element + 1`?", I mean "why _don't_ you have `list_element + 1` **when you print**?", if what you want is to show a number one larger than the index?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply to it using `enumerate` in Python, as follows:

```py
list = ["hello", "dad", "milk"]

for i, element in enumerate(list, 1): # to start with index 1, instead of 0
    print(f"[{i}] -{element}")
```

Result:

```
[1] -hello
[2] -dad
[3] -milk
```

You can get more informatoin and example about `enumerate` here:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/enumerate

In additon, one tip is that it is not good to use pre-defined keyword as a variable name such as `list`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `enumerate`.

```
myList = ["hello", "dad", "milk"]
for count, element in enumerate(myList):
    print(f"[{count+1}] -{element}")
```

Comment: I am curios what is the reason for a down vote for this. As I have noticed at least one more person suggested the same thing and get a similar down vote.